# stackoverflow exception loading war in jetty

Tags: jetty, war, stack-overflow

Loading war file using jetty,  the error is occured.
I don't know why this is occureed. because I hadn't have this problem on other operating system. But after I install it on Redhat Enterprise Linux, this error is occured.

I guess there are infinite loop..
in the log, you can see  "java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) is seen repatedly in the log.

Thanks in adavance.

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.maxBytesPerChar(CharsetEncoder.java:430) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.StringCoding$StringEncoder.encode(StringCoding.java:231) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.StringCoding.encode(StringCoding.java:272) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.String.getBytes(String.java:946) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes(UnixFileSystem.java:228) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.io.File.exists(File.java:733) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$FileLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:999) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:169) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:194) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    0000000at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
```

Comment: I solved this. the reason was that I set wrong classpath. but the jetty classloader kept trying like infinite loop. so the stack is overflowed. thanks.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the wrong classpath?  Would be good to catch that with an appropriate error.

Comment: Jetty is not even mentioned in that stacktrace.  It would be safe to say no Jetty code was even involved.